# *& Pointer in C program

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am Converting a  C++ code into C program. I come across a function that takes **void draw(char *&a)**. how to write this function *& in C program. I tried using same *&a but it is showing , (...etc expected. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: For c use `char**` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

There is no pass by reference in C. Therefore you need to change the function declaration to

```
void draw(char **a)
```

Comment: I changed function declaration to void draw(char **a) but its showing expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char *'

Comment: @karan; Show me how you called the function?

Comment: void towardDraw(char **a){ draw(a)}; void draw(char **ai){ int a,b,c,d,index=1000,i=1; FILE *f; f=fopen(ai, "r");}

Comment: Well, it should not.

Comment: yes. but it is not working.

Comment: @karan: You'll need to add `&` to the function call to pass a pointer rather than a reference. So if the C++ does `draw(p)` for some `char * p`, then C will need `draw(&p)`.

Comment: @karan: And also dereference the pointer when you use it in that function, to get the `char*` it points to. So in the code you've posted, `fopen(*ai, "r");`. Although, if the function doesn't need to modify the argument, then it should just take it by value, `char *a`, in both languages.